# editing this assembly code to only use add/subtract/shift

Tags: c, assembly, x86

```
        .file   "calcnew.c"
        .text
.globl calcnew
        .type   calcnew, @function
calcnew:
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        movl    8(%ebp), %edx
        movl    12(%ebp), %ecx
        leal    0(,%ecx,8), %eax
        subl    %ecx, %eax
        leal    (%edx,%edx,2), %edx
        addl    %edx, %eax
        imull   $14, 16(%ebp), %edx
        addl    %edx, %eax
        popl    %ebp
        ret
        .size   calcnew, .-calcnew
        .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.3.3-5ubuntu4) 4.3.3"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

I want to remove all `leal` and `imull` operations in this assembly code and replace their functionality with only `sall` `addl` and `subl` operations.  Here is my attempt:

```
    .file   "calcnew.c"
        .text
.globl calcnew
        .type   calcnew, @function
calcnew:
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        movl    8(%ebp), %edx
        movl    12(%ebp), %ecx
        sall    $3, %ecx
        movl    %ecx, %eax
        ;leal   0(,%ecx,8), %eax
        subl    %ecx, %eax
        movl    %edx, %ecx
        sall    $1, %edx
        addl    %ecx, %edx
        ;leal   (%edx,%edx,2), %edx
        addl    %edx, %eax
        movl    16(%ebp), %edx
        movl    %edx, %ecx
        sall    $4, %edx
        sall    $1, %ecx
        subl    %ecx, %edx
        ;imull  $14, 16(%ebp), %edx
        addl    %edx, %eax
        popl    %ebp
        ret
        .size   calcnew, .-calcnew
        .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.3.3-5ubuntu4) 4.3.3"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

The output when compiling my c code with the new assembly file should be the same as compiling with the original assembly file (using `leal` and `mull` operations), however, my output is wrong.  What did I do wrong?

Here is the C code calling the assembler file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int calcnew(int x, int y, int z);

int main()
{
        int x = 2;
        int y = 6;
        int z = 11;
        int result;

        result = calcnew(x,y,z);

        printf("x=%d, y=%d, z=%d, result=%d\n",x,y,z,result);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You replace

```
    leal    0(,%ecx,8), %eax
```

With

```
    sall    $3, %ecx
    movl    %ecx, %eax
```

But this clobbers the value of `ecx`, which is live out of those instructions. Instead:

```
    movl    %ecx, %eax
    sall    $3, %eax
```